# Parse GenCAD file to python lists

Tags: python, list, parsing

I am new to python. In my first little project I want to **parse** `GenCAD` output file and assign the `$PARTS$` content to a python list of lists data structure for further procesing.

The file to import:

```
$HEADER$
BOARD_TYPE PCB_DESIGN
UNITS MM
$END HEADER$

$PARTS$
CONN1                            CONN003081                       25.00        22.70        TOP      3
      1      25.00        20.70        SIGNALA
      2      25.00        21.70        SIGNALB
      3      25.00        22.70        SIGNALC
CONN2                            CONN003081                       31.50        45.00        TOP      3
      1      31.50        43.00        F-
      2      31.50        44.00        S-
      3      31.50        45.00        (Net0)
R1                               RESI100161                       29.89        46.50        TOP      2
      2      29.89        47.00        F+
      1      29.89        46.00        S+
$END PARTS$
...
```

I want something like that:

`print(parts[0]
['CONN1', 'CONN003081', '25.00', '22.70', 'TOP', '3', ['1', '25.00', '20.70', 'SIGNALA'], ['2', '25.00', '21.70', 'SIGNALB'], ['3', '25.00', '22.70', 'SIGNALC']]`

`print(parts[1])
['CONN2', 'CONN003081', '31.50', '45.00', 'TOP', '3', ['1', '31.50', '43.00', 'F-'], ['2', '31.50', '44.00', 'S-'], ['3', '31.50', '45.00', '(Net0)']]`

Comment: Can you please show us what you've tried?

Comment: We are happy to answer specific technical questions about your code, but we're not going to write code for you.

Comment: @larsks - this was such a nice sample case for using pyparsing, I couldn't resist. But you are right, in general, you can't just post "I want X" and just wait for someone to write X for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pyparsing is just right for this kind of task. Here is a pyparsing parser for your `$PARTS$` section - see the embedded comments:

```
from pyparsing import *

# define little expressions for the pieces in your input text
real = pyparsing_common.real
integer = pyparsing_common.integer
word = Word(alphas, alphanums+'_+-') | QuotedString('(', endQuoteChar=')', unquoteResults=False)

# combine the small expressions into more complex ones - use Group to retain structure
part_head   = Group(word + word + real + real + word + integer)
part_detail = Group(integer + real + real + word)

# define an overall part defn expression, and add results names to access the substructures
part_defn   = Group(part_head('head') + OneOrMore(part_detail)('details'))

# finally, define an expression for the input data section
parts_list = '$PARTS$' + Group(OneOrMore(part_defn)) + '$END PARTS'
```

And here is how you put the parser to use, and access the returned results:

```
# use searchString to find the $PARTS$ section, and parse its contents
# (searchString returns a list of matches, we just want the first one)
parts = parts_list.searchString(sample)[0]

# output using pretty-printing
parts.pprint()

# output, including results names
print(parts.dump())

# iterate over parts and access substructures
for part in parts[1]:
    print(part.head)
```

Gives:

```
['$PARTS$',
 [[['CONN1', 'CONN003081', 25.0, 22.7, 'TOP', 3],
   [1, 25.0, 20.7, 'SIGNALA'],
   [2, 25.0, 21.7, 'SIGNALB'],
   [3, 25.0, 22.7, 'SIGNALC']],
  [['CONN2', 'CONN003081', 31.5, 45.0, 'TOP', 3],
   [1, 31.5, 43.0, 'F-'],
   [2, 31.5, 44.0, 'S-'],
   [3, 31.5, 45.0, '(Net0)']],
  [['R1', 'RESI100161', 29.89, 46.5, 'TOP', 2],
   [2, 29.89, 47.0, 'F+'],
   [1, 29.89, 46.0, 'S+']]],
 '$END PARTS']

['$PARTS$', [[['CONN1', 'CONN003081', 25.0, 22.7, 'TOP', 3], [1, 25.0, ...
[0]:
  $PARTS$
[1]:
  [[['CONN1', 'CONN003081', 25.0, 22.7, 'TOP', 3], [1, 25.0, 20.7, ...
  [0]:
    [['CONN1', 'CONN003081', 25.0, 22.7, 'TOP', 3], [1, 25.0, 20.7, ...
    - details: [[1, 25.0, 20.7, 'SIGNALA'], [2, 25.0, 21.7, 'SIGNALB'],...
      [0]:
        [1, 25.0, 20.7, 'SIGNALA']
      [1]:
        [2, 25.0, 21.7, 'SIGNALB']
      [2]:
        [3, 25.0, 22.7, 'SIGNALC']
    - head: ['CONN1', 'CONN003081', 25.0, 22.7, 'TOP', 3]
  [1]:
    [['CONN2', 'CONN003081', 31.5, 45.0, 'TOP', 3], [1, 31.5, 43.0, 'F-'], ...
    - details: [[1, 31.5, 43.0, 'F-'], [2, 31.5, 44.0, 'S-'], [3, 31.5, ...
      [0]:
        [1, 31.5, 43.0, 'F-']
      [1]:
        [2, 31.5, 44.0, 'S-']
      [2]:
        [3, 31.5, 45.0, '(Net0)']
    - head: ['CONN2', 'CONN003081', 31.5, 45.0, 'TOP', 3]
  [2]:
    [['R1', 'RESI100161', 29.89, 46.5, 'TOP', 2], [2, 29.89, 47.0, 'F+'], ...
    - details: [[2, 29.89, 47.0, 'F+'], [1, 29.89, 46.0, 'S+']]
      [0]:
        [2, 29.89, 47.0, 'F+']
      [1]:
        [1, 29.89, 46.0, 'S+']
    - head: ['R1', 'RESI100161', 29.89, 46.5, 'TOP', 2]
[2]:
  $END PARTS

['CONN1', 'CONN003081', 25.0, 22.7, 'TOP', 3]
['CONN2', 'CONN003081', 31.5, 45.0, 'TOP', 3]
['R1', 'RESI100161', 29.89, 46.5, 'TOP', 2]
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much Paul. Your solution with pyparsing works very well. But if I use a sample were the net name SIGNALA is somthing like $1N1197 pyparsing returns an errror:  line 322, in __getitem__
    return self.__toklist[i]
IndexError: list index out of range  Do you have any idea? Unfortunally, these $1N... names are very common in the EDA world.

Comment: Change `word = Word(alphas, alphanums+'_+-') | QuotedString('(', endQuoteChar=')', unquoteResults=False)` to `word = Word(alphas+'$', alphanums+'_+-') | QuotedString('(', endQuoteChar=')', unquoteResults=False)`.